# c# Api Json deserializes when 404, values are wrong

Tags: c#, json, api, null, deserialization

I have a code that access a `Api` link and retrieves that `Json` values and stores them in a `object list`. However when there is nothing to retrieve (Link to the Api doesnt exist) it returns nothing.

However even though the Api link is wrong it still returns Json values. These are their default values that will always be there even though there is nothing that matches the ID requested.

[Correct Api Json value](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/Preserved%20Queen%20Bee)

Below link will show values that will always return no matter what

[INCorrect Api Json value](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/xxxx)

here is where i call to the Api

```
var spidyApi_idByName_result = api_Handler.objFromApi_nameToId(spidyApi_searchIdByName);
```

Here the Api is accessed and the Json is deserialized.

```
public RootObject objFromApi_nameToId(string url){
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            try{
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()){
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException){
                throw;
                // used throw as otherwise i can not run code, function requires every path to return
                // Catch never gets called

            }
        }
```

RootObject class

```
public RootObject GetApi(string url)
{
    // ...
    return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
}
```

How do i go around and ignore their "default" json values? just do nothing.

Comment: Does your RootObject have a property called count in it?

Comment: yes it does. `public int count { get; set; }`

Comment: What is the expected system behavior for an incorrect API? Are you expecting it to return a null object from your objFromApi_nameToId method?

Comment: What do you mean, expected system behavior?

Comment: When you say ignore their default json values, what do you mean. The json will return. It will deserialize into your root object. But you want to ignore this object because it returned from an invalid api call?

Comment: Yes, if only these default json values are returned i basicly dont want to do anything. No object should be made, nothing should be added to the list. Or when i try to access the list it will return a null value which will break all code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the defaults in your code. E.g. Your invalid API example will always return the count as 0. You can now use that condition to decide your program flow.

```
RootObject rootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);

if (rootObject.count > 0)
    return rootObject;
else
    return null; //or any other program flow you need to execute.
```